# How to Store Server IP in apache log file

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, ubuntu, autoscaling

I am using an AWS AutoScaling Group. Here i have hosted Apche-Ubuntu instances. I want to log which server served the content, by logging its ip.

Closest I have found is this
https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1401710.html (February 11th, 2010, 04:07 PM) comment.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache you can use the directive [LogFormat](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#logformat) which allows you to determine what information is included in the header of each log.  You create LogFormat strings in the apache2.conf, then use those strings when you use the [CustomLog](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) directive.

Example used in the Apache help:

```
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
CustomLog "logs/access_log" common
```

This means that the logs in access_log will have this information included:

- Remote Host Name
- Remote logname
- Remote User
- Time
- First line of request (put in quotes)
- Final status
- Size of the request in bytes

In the [log formats documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#formats) there is a `%A -  Local IP-address`

I have never tested it, but it might work for what you need.

Comment: Keep in mind that if these AutoScaling instances are behind a Classic or Application load balancer, the IP you'll see in the logs as the 'client' will be the load balancers IP.  You'll need Apache to log the "X-Forwarded-For" header to see the actual client IP